# How can I make a three.js sprite face towards a specific vector?

Tags: canvas, three.js, sprite

I'm using Three.JS revision 68. I want to make a sphere of little circular sprites, as if the little circular sprites were the "skin" of the sphere. The problem is that the circular sprites I created using canvas should all face the center of this (non-existent) sphere, but they are parallel to the screen instead:

[image]

I tried to use the lookAt(vector) method that Sprites should understand as they are subclasses of Object3D, but it's completely ignored and the sprites don't change the direction they are facing:

```
sphereOfSprites = new THREE.Object3D(),

camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    var container, particles, particle;

    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 1000;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


    var radius = 250;
    var numOfSpikes = 200;
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfSpikes; i++) {

        particle = new THREE.Sprite( new THREE.SpriteMaterial( {
            map: new THREE.Texture( generateCircularSprite("white") ),
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending    } ) );
        particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        particle.position.normalize();
        particle.position.multiplyScalar( radius );
        particle.scale.multiplyScalar( 25 );

        // HERE IS WHERE I TRY TO MAKE THE SPRITE PARTICLE LOOK TOWARDS THE CENTER OF THE SPHERE
        vector.copy( particle.position );
        particle.lookAt(vector);
        sphereOfSprites.add( particle );
    }
    scene.add(sphereOfSprites)
}


function generateCircularSprite(color) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.height = 100;
    canvas.width = 100;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 50;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
    return canvas;
}
```

What can I use for making the sprites face towards the direction I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Add to the answer by Leeft, You are also telling the particle to "look" at itself with:

```
vector.copy( particle.position );
    particle.lookAt(vector);
```

I think you mean:

```
particle.lookAt(sphereOfSprites.position);
```

I have created a jsfiddle which uses a planeGeometry as suggested by Leeft and also the small change I suggest above.
See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yxtp8g4q/

Comment: Thank you for your time! BTW, I used particle.position because I thought lookAt expected a "direction" as an argument and not the "actual target point" of where I want the object to look at. Thanks for that as well!

Answer (score 1):

Sprites have a special kind of rendering, and thus you always see them straight on (they're not even facing the camera, they're always flat on the screen). To do what you want to do you'll have to create your own objects instead.